# Javascript two popups at page load

Tags: javascript, popup

i'm bugging with this problem for couple of days for now. So, my question is how i should write js code, to popup 2 different popups on a page1.html load, and to keep this main page on focus. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var params = "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
window.open("page1.html", "Page 1", params);
window.open("page2.html", "Page 2", params);
window.focus();
```

But consider that fact that in Firefox for example using of `window.focus()` can be prohibited by the user.

Comment: Window names cannot have spaces in Internet Explorer. This will trip over most popup blockers.

Comment: thank you for your post, and @DAvid Dorward thank you too for this notice. :)

Answer (score -1):

use this

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "Key", "window.open('popupnew.aspx?QueryString "', 'newwindow','toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,width=500,height=300,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=200,left=250')", False)

Comment: Where is `ScriptManager` supposed to come from? And your quotes are unbalanced. And the question was for two popups. And if that does what I think it is trying to do, then it will get blocked by most popup blockers.